# Why two lines of code that should have equivalent funcion but the final run results are different?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am solving a python code [problem](https://dmoj.ca/problem/crci06p1).
Here are my code:

```
n = int(input())
e = int(input())

dict0 = {i:set() for i in range(1, n+1)}

for i in range(e):
    k, *villagers = map(int, input().split())
    if 1 in villagers:
        for j in range(k):
            dict0[villagers[j]] = dict0[villagers[j]] | set([i])
            # dict0[villagers[j]].add(i) # In my view, this line should update one set in dictionary, but it will update more than one set in this line, why is that?
    else:
        union_set = set()
        for j in range(k):
            union_set |= dict0[villagers[j]]
        for j in range(k):
            dict0[villagers[j]] = union_set

for i in dict0:
    if dict0[i] == dict0[1]:
        print(i)
```

Sample inputs:

```
8
5
4 1 3 5 4
2 5 6
3 6 7 8
2 6 2
4 2 6 8 1
```

Why do these two lines of code:

```
dict0[villagers[j]] = dict0[villagers[j]] | set([i])

dict0[villagers[j]].add(i)
```

produce different results?

In my code line 11 and line 12 should have same function, but in the end they don't produce the same results.
I tried to print out the dictionary in the loop and if i use line 12, it will update more than one set in the dictionary.
I couldn't figure out how this happend and why. Please help me find out the reason. Thanks so much.

Comment: `add` mutates an existing set, `s1 | s2` creates a new set.

Comment: An after your `else` case multiple entries in your dictionary will point to the same `set` instance. Therefore mutating that shared `set` instance will affect multiple dictionary entires.

Comment: Also `a = set(); print(id(a)); a.add(1); print(id(a)); a = a | set(); print(id(a))` - see that the first one does not create a new set / prints the same id while the second does create a new one.

Comment: So the key point is that multiple entries in dictionary can point to the same set instance, i don't know that.

Comment: The real problem comes from the line `dict0[villagers[j]] = union_set`. You are assigning the same set to all dictionary values

Comment: @empshock That's correct. An assignment with `=` never (!) copies data. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) for details.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments post by timgeb and luk2302, | creates new set and add() modify existing set and dictionary can have multiple entries point to the same set. Use id() to look at objects id.
And set.copy should be used to copy sets.